# How to change JDK version from 11 to 8 on a local file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, java-11

I am wondering how to change the JDK version from 11 to 8 on my local file.

I already change the environment variables on windows and it already reflects the version I need.

[image: Click this link to see the JDK 8 VERSION using windows terminal:]

However if I tried to check the JDK version opening the terminal on my local project file it still reflects the JDK 11 version.

[image: Click here to see the error]

Comment: Please don't put your code and errors behind images. Copy/paste them here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: is that on two different machines?

Comment: seems like your "local project" (not sure what you really mean by that, maybe starting from some  IDE?) is using the Power Shell and not using the environment variables as the Windows Command Interpreter (command prompt)

Comment: No. Same laptop is used, however the jdk version for my project file wont reflect the jdk version I need. I also even deleted the variable path for JDK 11 in environment variables settings in windows.

Comment: @user16320675  the normal cmd prompt and pwershell is reflecting jdk 8 only when I tried to open a terminal from a local folder (for a springboot project) where it wont show the desired jdk version.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire sincerest apologies. I'm so new here and in tech in general. I am so lost..

Comment: maybe better explain how you are opening "a terminal from a local folder" (add to question using the [edit] link here or just below the question)

Comment: @user16320675 desktop>git_clones_files>location-service (right click anywhere to open a terminal from this specific folder).

Comment: Exactly which environment variables are you changing and exactly how are you changing  them?

Comment: You can type `Get-Command java` in the PowerShell window to see the path of the Java executable and `where java` in the Command Prompt window to see the path to the Java executable. The paths are determined by the value of the `PATH` environment variable. It appears something is changing it, otherwise both paths, i.e. Command Prompt and PowerShell, should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Everyone.

This is to inform that this issue is already fixed. What I did was simply uninstalled both my java 8 & java 11, and then re-installed java 8 on my local device and everything is now working.

I appreciate everyone who comment on this post.

Have a great day!